# Joomla component output - only template - no default site skeleton

Tags: joomla, components

Hi is possible somehow output only content of single view/template in joomla component?As standard I put the output into according part of whole site, but I have some action which is called by robot, so I need to have custom output..

the component output is commonly rendered somewhere on default site template, but I need to only respond with the markup in the component output..

Please help, I've googled for some time, but founded nothing:(
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append ?tmpl=component to any Joomla URL to have use the component.php file in the root of you template directory. That file can be customized to display anything you want, the default only displays the bare minimum HTML around the component output.

Comment: ye it works..But there is still a lot of stuff in head, I only need to output `<html><head></head><body>[OK]</body></html>` thats all..is it possible?

Comment: so I have found I can simply change the component.php file in my default template folder..But it would affect too other components, can I anyhow split this component.php file for more components?

and I have there problems when I delete jdoc inlude head? can I anywhere customize included head?

Comment: Make a copy of the component.php and put it in your template folder, then edit that. It should only affect pages when the tmpl=component parameter is in the URL.